Anyone know the meaning of the point with "?" on the map?
Zak McKracken: anyone know after Zak has the yellow crystal and its knowledge (taken from  shaman) can go on some points on map

I can go in Mars, Perù, Mexico, Egypt but when I click in center (I put a red arrow)
nothing happen. It is a bug, or incomplete stuff? Or other?

If you're the one who downvoted my answer, well, it's updated now.

I put + vote now and marked as solution answer

Thank BKelly95 on TVTropes:
That dot's a broken teleporter to:

 Atlantis

It's located under:

 The Bermuda Triangle

And can be seen in this video, or read about here.
You need the Blue Crystal to actually see the broken teleporter.
